# Plots in matplotlib overlapping when I'm sending two requests at the same time

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, charts, rest

I having a problem with Flask and matplotlib. I wrote a simple API that returns a chart from matplotlib. When two users send a request at the same time charts overlap themselves even though I created separate classes for charts.

Here is my code:

```
class WykresXT:
    def make(self, amp, okres):
        name = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        time = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
        plot.plot(time, calc_xt(amp=float(amp), czas=time, okres_d=float(okres)))
        plot.title('Wykres x(t)')
        plot.xlabel('t (czas)')
        plot.ylabel('x (wychylenie)')
        plot.grid(True, which='both')
        plot.axhline(y=0, color='k')
        plot.savefig(str(name) + '.png')
        plot.close()
        plot.figure().clear()
        return str(name) + '.png'


@app.route('/wykres_x', methods=['GET'])
def wykres_x():
    args = {"amp": request.args.get('amp'), "okres": request.args.get('okres'), "faza": request.args.get('faza')}
    if args["amp"] is not None and args["okres"] is not None and args["faza"] is not None:
        wykres = WykresXT()
        return send_file(wykres.make(args["amp"], args["faza"], args["okres"]))
    else:
        return "podaj: '?amp=' '&okres=' '&faza='"
```

And an example of the overlapping issue:

[image: example of overlapping charts]

Comment: Meaning the second user's plot is plotted directly over the first user's plot? A screencap might be helpful.

Comment: @tdy [link](https://imgur.com/gallery/Dk1s7dm) this is how charts look

Comment: When you call something like `plt.plot`, it operates on your current figure. Try to use the other notation, i.e., `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, `ax.plot`, .... Each user will have its own figure and axis object, so overlap shouldn't be an issue. Try it and see how it goes.

Comment: @K.Cl the thing is that there might be more than two users that accidentaly send a request at the same time

Comment: What I'm imagining is that two users send a request at the same time, i. e., before matplotlib finished generating its current figure. So when two calls are made simultaneously, matplotlib thinks its dealing with the same figure when it processes the commands. If you explicitly create two fig and axis objects specific to each call, matplotlib won't confuse them.

Comment: I'm saying 2 calls and 2 figs/axis, but that can be n calls and n separate objects.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example and what you're doing to cause this, so I can test on my machine?

Comment: @K.Cl https://github.com/vjasieg/FizykaAPI/blob/master/main.py here is my code, if you send two requests to /wykres_x?amp=5&okres=10 at the same time it will crash or you'll get two overlapped charts in response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to reproduce your bug and have managed to fix it on my end. Test over there and see if it works for you.

I created this script to send multiple requests at once, taken from another SO post.

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_url(url):
        return requests.get(url)

list_of_urls = [
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=5&okres=10',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=10&okres=10',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=15&okres=10',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=20&okres=10',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=5&okres=15',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=10&okres=20',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=5&okres=30',
        'http://0.0.0.0:25565/wykres_x?amp=10&okres=40'
        ]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
        print(list(pool.map(get_url,list_of_urls)))
```

When I ran this while your server was running, I got some colorful graphs, as expected.

Then, I changed the pyplot calls from implicit to explicit, as I mentioned in the comments. Here's your class.

```
class WykresXT:
    def make(self, amp, okres):
        name = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        time = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
        fig, ax = plot.subplots()  # <-- here is the start of the different part
        ax.plot(time, calc_xt(amp=float(amp), czas=time, okres_d=float(okres)))
        ax.set_title('Wykres x(t)')
        ax.set_xlabel('t (czas)')
        ax.set_ylabel('x (wychylenie)')
        ax.grid(True, which='both')
        ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
        fig.savefig(str(name) + '.png') # <-- end of the modified part
        plot.close()
        plot.figure().clear()
        return str(name) + '.png'
```

It now created a bunch of figures, all separated as you wanted.